# How to differentiate between InvalidOperationException exception types?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, invalidoperationexception

How to detect the InvalidOperationException type

Here is the inner exception message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

I need to detect exactly this type of exceptions to handle it.
Can I know its HResult number or the exception code? or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help

```
try
{
    //your code here...
}
catch (Exception exception) when (exception.InnerException is InvalidOperationException)
{
    var exceptionMessage = "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection";
    if (exception.Message.Contains(exceptionMessage) || exception.InnerException.Message.Contains(exceptionMessage))
    {
        //handle it...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/catch exception handling hierarchy, so that InvalidOperationException will be caught first and handled separately from other exception types such as the generic exception type.

```
try
{
    // Normal workflow up here
}
catch (System.InvalidOperationException ioex)
{
    // Handle InvalidOperationException
    Console.WriteLine(ioex.StackTrace);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    // Handle generic exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

However, your question suggests that this will not work for you, because you mention an **inner exception**. In that case you probably need to do some type checking on the inner exception like this:

```
try
{
    // Normal workflow up here
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is InvalidOperationException) 
    { 
        // Handle InvalidOperationException
    }
    else 
    { 
        // Handle generic exception
    } 

    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us more context? It would make it easier for us to answer your question.

However, if I understand you correctly, you try to process 'something' with the inner exception. As of C# 6 there are *exception filters* available. For more information about exception filters see [Exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#exception-filters).

The documentation also provides an example.

In your specific case, you could use the exception filter as follows:

```
try
{
    // Do something that could cause a InvalidOperationException
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SomeTypeOfException)
{
    // Handle this type of exception
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is AnotherSomeTypeOfException)
{
    // Handle this kind of exception
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but as I know that the System.InvalidOperationException is thrown in many cases and I need to handle it in this specific case (when the message is like "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed"). Also, I don't need to compare the exception message as a string.